# How to explain this expression?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

In a paper, it says: Infinitesimally, around a point $p$, $f$ may be expressed with respect to its
local parameter as follows:
$$f(z)\approx f(p)+f_z(p)z+f_\bar{z}(p)\bar{z}$$

How to get this?

Comment: $\bar z$ is usually the conjugate of $z$.

Comment: This is probably a typo.  Also, you have a typo in your formula:  should be $\bar{z}-\bar{p}$

Comment: It's a differential approximation. (once you correct it)